# Displaying 2 queries in nested loops mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$champions = $conn->prepare("SELECT Champion, Q, Q2, W, W2, E, E2, R, R2 
            FROM champions 
            Where Patch_No = ?");
            $champions->bind_param('s', $Patch_No);
            $champions->execute();
            $champions_result = $champions->get_result();

            $spells = $conn ->prepare("
            SELECT Champion, Spell_Change, Spell_Change_Icon, Spell_Type
            FROM spells
            WHERE Patch_No= ?
            ");
            $spells->bind_param('s', $Patch_No);
            $spells->execute();
            $spells_result = $spells->get_result();                 


            while($row = $champions_result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo $row['Champion'].'<br>';
                foreach ($row as $column_name => $column) {
                    if ($column_name == 'Champion') {
                        continue; // These fields were already displayed above
                    }
                    if (!empty($column)) {
                        echo "$column_name $column<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is how the spell table looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYSC0.png 
and here is champions table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGAWM.png

Champions table right now displays

1. Name of the Champion

   -Spells of that champion e.g. Q W E R - name of that spell

   *And here I want all the changes from Spell table that happened to those spells

Here is how it looks like right now https://i.stack.imgur.com/grnnr.png

And here is an example of how it should look like after displaying both tables at once: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHRpF.jpg